# How to remove only one path from a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, path

I want to either remove, change the colour of or change the position of the second line.

Also, is there a way to make the colour of an already created line different?

```
var cvs = document.querySelector('#canvas')
        var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d')
        cvs.height = window.innerHeight - 40
        cvs.width = window.innerWidth - 40
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            cvs.height = window.innerHeight - 40;
            cvs.width = window.innerWidth - 40;

        })
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
        ctx.lineWidth = '5'
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'
        ctx.moveTo(200, 600)
        ctx.lineto(100,100)
        ctx.closePath();
         //Second path which is what i want to remove only
               ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
            ctx.lineWidth = '37px'
            ctx.moveTo(100,100)
            ctx.lineTo(300, 500)
            ctx.stroke()
            ctx.closePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects painted on the canvas cannot be modified, but they can be **painted over**. Unlike HTML or SVG, the the canvas does not have its own DOM, so there is no way to access objects that have already painted on the canvas.

**Approach 1:**

The most common approach is to **clear the canvas**, adjust any attributes (position, color, etc), **and repaint the objects** onto the canvas.

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height) //removes everything from the canvas
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.lineWidth = '5'
ctx.lineCap = 'round'
ctx.moveTo(200, 600)
ctx.lineTo(100,100)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath(); //repaints the first object, the second path is gone.
```

**Pros:**

- more robust: will work in all situations (even when objects overlap)
- Scales well: better when lots of objects are painted

**Cons:**

- every object has to be repainted on the canvas. (removes everything)

**Approach 2:**

The closest approach to removing a single object, it **paints over the existing object** and **repaint it somewhere else**.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white' //background color
ctx.lineWidth = '37px'
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(300, 500);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath(); // covers up the second path

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
ctx.lineWidth = '37px'
ctx.moveTo(100,100)
ctx.lineTo(600, 500) //repaint this object somewhere else
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath()
```

**Pros:**

- Only removes the second path, leaves everything else
- simpler when fewer objects are on the canvas

**Cons:**

- **Will not work** when objects overlap.
- Does not scale well: this solution will get more complex when more objects are being modified.

More resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial